# Creating a preview page feature in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am new to Laravel and I am creating content management system as practice to get familiar with the framework. Currently, I am working on the feature for the user to preview the information they have entered for updating the new page they want to create and here is code for the view:

```
<div ng-controller="PagesController">
<form action="{{url('admin/page/preview')}}" method="post" name="pageForm">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Title</label>
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-md" name="title" ng-model="page.title">
                 </div>
                    <!-- <input type="submit" value="Preview"> -->
              </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <fieldset style="border: 1px solid #E4E4E4; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <label>Add File</label>
                            <input type="file" name="upload" nv-file-select uploader="updateUploader" value="Select Picture" ng-model="page.upload" >
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Progress</th>
                                        <th>Actions</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr ng-repeat="item in updateUploader.queue">
                                        <td style="max-width: 170px; word-wrap: break-word;" ng-cloak><strong>@{{ item.file.name}}</strong></td>
                                        <td><div class="col-md-12"><progressbar value="item.progress"></progressbar></div></td>
                                        <td nowrap ng-cloak>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="item.remove()">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove
                                        </button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div><br>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Body</label>
                    <input type="hidden"  name="body" value="@{{page.body}}"/>
                    <summernote  name="body" ng-model="page.body" config="options" height="300"></summernote>

                    <div ng-messages="pageForm.body.$error" ng-if="pageForm.body.$dirty">
                        <div ng-message="required">
                            <span class="error-msgs">Please enter page information</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-left">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="checkbox col-md-12 text-left">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" value="" ng-model"page.serivice" ng-false-value="0" ng-true-value="1" ><strong>Update page to services</strong></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
               <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-left">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="update" ng-disabled="pageForm.$invalid" ng-click="update()">Update</button>
                   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-md" value="Preview">
                 </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default general-panel publish" style="margin-top: 35px;">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="title">Navigation</div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <span class="">
                    <i></i><strong>Parent pages</strong>&nbsp;
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <select class="form-control" name="publish_period" ng-model="page.parent_nav">
                            <option value="">No Parent Navigation</option>
                            <option value="about-us">About Us</option>
                            <option value="media">Media</option>
                            <option value="publication">Publication</option>
                            <option value="law">Law</option>
                            <option value="legislation">Legislation</option>
                            <option value="compliance">Compliance</option>
                            <option value="license">Applying For License</option>
                        </select>
                    </div><br><br>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default general-panel general-summary">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="3"><h5>Uploaded Documents</h5></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>      
                <tr ng-repeat="document in documents">
                    <td style="max-width: 100px; word-wrap: break-word;">@{{document.file_path}}</td>
                    <td>
                       <a href="{{ url('admin/downloadfile') }}/@{{document.id}}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-download fa-fw"></i>Download</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is the code for the route for previewing the page:

```
  Route::post('page/preview','PagesController@preview');
```

and the controller method for the preview function:

```
public function preview(Request $request)
{

   return view('admin.pages.preview')->with('title',$request->input('title'))->with('body',$request->input('body'));
}
```

This works for me, but when I refreshed the preview page it would generate an error saying BadMethodCallException. So I am wondering how can eliminate this from happening? and thanks in advance.

Comment: refreshing creates a get request, your controller action responds to (and relies upon data from) a post request

Comment: To get around this, you can persist the data you need (eg into session, or database) then redirect to a route that responds to get requests, and pulls its required data from the session/db

Comment: Okay, I will look using the session feature in laravel

Comment: Steve is right: actually, you could implement a stub system for your CMS with database storage... something like post versioning! :) However, use a database for it. Avoid sessions when you can.

Comment: alright then, thanks for heads up